# adding image to different div upon change/removal of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

I have a game which involves a dog chasing cats; upon the dog touching the cat `div`, the class changes so that a "dead" cat appears and is then removed. I would also like to have a smaller version of the dead cat image show up in a `div` in the upper right corner as a sort of score keeper. 
So essentially every time a cat is killed a small image pops up in the score `div`. 
The problem is if I have the `prepend` for the small image placed where it is now, it continues to add the image indefinitely as opposed to only one for each dead cat. I'm guessing it's because it's within this if statement for the collision detection but I can't figure out a way around it.
I've tried making it a function, moving it outside of the `getCollision` function, tried to attach a trigger...nothing I've done seems to work to solve what I assume to be a relatively simple problem.

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it! Below is the code:

```
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log("linked");

var $dog = $('.dog'); //global variables
var body = $('body');
var $cat = $('.cat');

function newCat() { //creates a div w/ class cat, appends to body
    var cat = $('<div class="cat"></div>');
    body.append(cat);
    setInterval(function() { //moves cats randomly
        cat.css("top", Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
        cat.css("left", Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
    }, 1500)
}

  for(var i=0; i<10; i++) { //create multiple cats
      newCat();
  }

function getCollision(cat) { //collision detection for elements
    $(cat).each(function(index, cat) { //loops through each cat div
        var $dogH = $dog.outerHeight(true);
        var $dogW = $dog.outerWidth(true);
        var $dogX = $dog.position();
        var $dogY = $dog.position();

        var $catH = parseInt($(cat).css('height').replace('px', ''))
        var $catW = parseInt($(cat).css('width').replace('px', ''))
        var $catX = parseInt($(cat).css('left').replace('px', ''))
        var $catY = parseInt($(cat).css('top').replace('px', ''))


        if ($dogX.left < $catX + $catW &&
            $dogY.top < $catY + $catH &&
            $catX < $dogX.left + $dogW &&
            $catY < $dogY.top + $dogW) {
            $(cat).addClass('dead');
             $('.score').prepend('<img src="images/cat_dead_sm.png" />');
            setTimeout(function() {
              $('.dead').remove(); //removes dead cat
            }, 2500);
            console.log('boom');
        };
    });
};


$(document).mousemove(function(event) { //moves dog div to follow cursor
    $('.dog').css({
        'top': event.pageY,
        'bottom': event.pageX,
        'left': event.pageX,
        'right': event.pageY
    });
    $cat = $('.cat')
    getCollision($cat); //calls getcollision to check distance
})();


// function keepScore() {
//      $('.score').prepend('<img src="images/cat_dead_sm.png" />');
//   }
// };

});
```

Comment: in addition to @Brian's comment it appears you're passing a whole jQuery object into your collision function, but then within the function you're treating the argument as a string try `getCollision('.cat'); //calls getcollision to check distance` instead, and then secondly I would recommend using `each()` with `$(this)` to target specific cat's as at present it appears there are moments where all `.cat`'s risk being targetted simultaneously. If you could assemble a jsfiddle it would be easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that a dead cat can still die - another iteration of the collision detection can occur before the setTImeout that removes the dead cat is triggered. You could check if the current cat is already dead before prepending the score image.

We just need to check if it's already dead to avoid this:

```
if ($dogX.left < $catX + $catW &&
    $dogY.top < $catY + $catH &&
    $catX < $dogX.left + $dogW &&
    $catY < $dogY.top + $dogW &&
    !$(cat).hasClass('dead')
) {
    $(cat).addClass('dead');
    $('.score').prepend('<img src="images/cat_dead_sm.png" />');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.dead').remove(); //removes dead cat
    }, 2500);
    console.log('boom');
}
```

Or even better - you could avoid collision detection on dead cats entirely:

```
$cat = $('.cat:not(.dead)'); 
getCollision($cat);
```

Comment: avoiding the collision detection on dead cats worked beautifully, thank you!

Comment: Glad be if assistance! Would you mind marking it as the correct answer please :) Cheers, Brian